# Different background on each Listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a Listbox containing item binding on my table that consist of 5 columns (idStory, title, created, textStory, and feeling).

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Height="418" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="listPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="#e34d64" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="26" Foreground="Black"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Created}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextStory}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" FontStyle="Italic"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="menuEdit" Header="Edit Story" Click="menuEdit_Click"/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="menuDelete" Header="Delete Story" Click="menuDelete_Click"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

It works well, but i want to change the background on each item depends on column feeling. For example if we get string "sad" then the listbox item will have blue as a background like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWNtQ.jpg

What should i do for making it real? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've removed a tag from question's title. Please note that in most cases questions [shouldn't include tags in their title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: Oh, i am so sorry. Thank you

Comment: @Romaz Tags are fine in the title if they are integrated in a fluid manner as was done in this question (see the second example in your link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose I would propose binding Background of your TextBox (or maybe better whole StackPanel - your choice) to Feeling property with a Converter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="26" Foreground="Black" Background={Binding Feeling, Converter={StaticResource TxtToBrush}}/>
```

You will have to add key to your Converter somewhere in the Resources:

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Yournamespace"
<conv:TextToBrush x:Key="TxtToBrush"/>
```

And the Converter can look like this:

```
public class TextToBrush : IValueConverter
{
    List<Tuple<string, Brush>> textBrush = new List<Tuple<string, Brush>>()
    {
        new Tuple<string, Brush>("sad", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue))
    };

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        else
        {
            foreach (Tuple<string,Brush> item in textBrush)
                if ((value as string) == item.Item1) return item.Item2 as Brush;
        }
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And of course your Property `BGColor` should raise `OnPropertyChanged` (your item class should impement `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

Comment: Hei, thank you. I make converter and it's look like better. But now i try to set image as my background. Is it possible if i set my stackpanel properties like ImageSource="{Binding some_url_of_my_asset}" ?

Comment: @SonicMaster StackPanel doesn't have a property ImageSource. You can surely bind ImageSource of your Image (you will find many answer on SO). If you want to set your Image as Background, you may be interested in [ImageBrush class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx). You can make another property which getter would return for example imagebrush.

Comment: @SonicMaster You are welcome. Remember that if one of the answers solved your problem, don't forget to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).